# How do I convert easejs path to svg

Tags: javascript, createjs

I have a js file created using ease.js which creates some shapes in canvas. 
But I dont want to use canvas. I want to implement it using svg.

Is there a way to convert path file to svg file?

Code written using easyjs

```
(lib.FlashMuxSymbol = function() {
    this.initialize();

    // Layer 1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f().s("#000000").ss(1.5,1,1).p("ABuhcIjDghQgZAAAAAaIAACPQAAAaAZAAIDDghgAB5gYIA8AAAi0haIA8AAAi0AsIA8AAAALBCIAAA8");
    this.shape.setTransform(18.3,15.1);

    this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_1.graphics.f("#432F26").s().p("AAfA1IAAhSIgVBSIgTAAIgVhSIAABSIgVAAIAAhpIAhAAIASBHIAThHIAgAAIAABpg");
    this.shape_1.setTransform(17.8,11.8);

    this.addChild(this.shape_1,this.shape);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Container();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0.2,2.5,36.2,25.3);
```

Comment: Normally I would incline to say *no*! But you should paste some js code. I for one don't know what exactly ease.js exports, but if it's a clean code it may be somehow parsed and translated into svg, but it's a veeeery long shot.

Comment: What does your path data structure/syntax look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone stumbling onto this question in the future: EaselJS now includes an `SVGExporter` class in the `extras/` directory. This will export almost any EaselJS content to SVG, including vector graphics.

https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/tree/master/extras/SVGExporter

Answer (score 0):

you may use online SVG editor:

http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.6/editor/svg-editor.html

it hasan edit source feature so you may take the canvas and change it a bit to match svg syntax.

Comment: Thanks, but my aim is not creating svg. I can do that in inkscape.
My aim is converting the js code I have into svg.

Comment: what does this js create ? (shape?)

Comment: Yes it creates a shape on canvas.